# Handling continue and exit handler in snowflake

Tags: db2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone please tell me how to handle continue and exit handler execeptions in snowflake?

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_atend=1;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '22003'
BEGIN
  SET p_errorMsg = 'SQLSTATE 22003 - Numeric overflow occurred setting bonus';
END;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET v_atend=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Snowflake try catch block to catch System defined exception or Custom Functions too.

One of sample code i had taken from this url would help you to understand how to handle errors in Snowflake.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#label-stored-procedure-error-handling

```
create procedure broken()
      returns varchar not null
      language javascript
      as
      $$
      var result = "";
      try {
          snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "Invalid Command!;"} );
          result = "Succeeded";
          }
      catch (err)  {
          result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
          result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
          result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt; 
          }
      return result;
      $$
      ;
```